# How to detect if a user is logged in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

I need to know how I can get if a specific user in symfony is logged in the application, 
is there a way to get the session id for the current users logged?

I've tried with a table when I have a field named `is_online` and y set it when the user loggin and logout on the application, so I get a problem when a user close the brower or when the session end, so the field `is_online` stay true. That is the reason for that I need another way to get if an user is logged on the application.

Any advice will be useful.

Answer (score 4):

You can send ajax request from users and as soon as someone doesn't send request for example 1 min change his status to offline. Will be good idea to store statuses in some key-value storage i.e MemCache. Look here for [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053388/check-what-users-are-online).

Comment: Thanks, this will be a solution, but by security if an application is in inactivity more than 15 minutes, the session has to close.

Comment: For example with an ajax request every 5 mins, the session never close.

Comment: I can't understand where are you going to use session for storing statuses or have I missed something?

Comment: I just want to get if an user is logged, y tell that user session_id() has close by security in 15 minutes in inactivity, with an ajax request every 5 mins, the sesion never close,and that can't be allowed.

Comment: you can send the ping ajax only if you detected that the user did something in the page (mouseevent or keypress, you can use a jquery plugin to do that), if the user leaves the browser open without doing anything no ping will be sent and the session will expire. I wouldn't recomend to store session data or statuses on memcache because you don't have guarantee of the persistence of the statuses store in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Create a database field like `lastonlinetstamp` and a `ping` method in ajax which calls a service with the same session every minute. Then let the ping service update the `lastonlinetstamp`. If this value is older than 1 minute you know the user is offline.
But: This will increase the number of requests to your server.